# border-radius na tabela não funciona CSS

Tags: html, css, table, css-border-radius

Estou tentando colocar um border-radius na minha tabela para que as 4 pontas dela fiquem arredondadas. Se eu mexer no border-radius do tr/th/td vai mudar o raio das cédulas e não somente os da tabela, que é meu objetivo e se eu mudar o raio da table e isso aparecer corretamente. Com a table marca que o raio diminuiu mas a tabela não acompanha isso, segue uma imagem pra ilustrar isso que eu falei:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CSS:

```
    .table-round-corner{
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    berder-radius: 25px;
    border: solid #ddd 1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
table td{
    color: #aaa;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
table th{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

HTML:

```
                    <table class"table-round-corner">
                        <tr>
                            <th>ASDASD</th>
                            <th>ASDASDAS</th>
                            <th>ASDASD</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ASDASD</td>
                            <td>34</td>
                            <td>R$ 00,00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ASDASDASD</td>
                            <td>00</td>
                            <td>R$ 00,00</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Resumo:

Preciso que minha tabela tenha as pontas arredondadas.

Comment: Não funciona porque você não está aplicando a regra na tabela.

Comment: Ah não, "`berder-radius: 25px;`".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Viva!

Penso que seja isto que você quer:

```css
.table-round-corner {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border: solid #ccc 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
       -moz-border-radius: 25px;
            border-radius: 25px;
}


table td {
    color: #aaa;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table th{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-round-corner" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th>ASDFASDF</th>
    <th>ASDFASDFASDFA</th>
    <th>ASDFASDF</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ASDFASDF</td>
    <td>654</td>
    <td>R$ 00,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SDFASDF</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>R$ 00,00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Pode-me mostrar 1 print de como está? Apenas para tentar perceber melhor o porquê de não ter funcionado.

Comment: Consegue abrir as Ferramentas de Programador do browser e seleccionar o elemento para ver as regras de css que estão a ser aplicadas? Entretanto alterei o CSS da class .table-round-corner, verifique se assim já funciona por favor.

Comment: Há! Achei o problema! Provavelmente, antes, não estava aparecendo corretamente por causa do overflow e agora estava escrito berder-radius(o que eu não sei como pq eu copiei o teu código O.O).

Answer (score 4):

Basta aplicar na tabela.

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Como está (aparentemente) utilizando Bootstrap, pode tentar dessa forma:

```css
/* só para manter a tabela centralizada */
.panel {
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 70% !important
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>foo</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Se ainda assim não funcionar pode ser que alguma outra regra esteja sobrepondo o `border-radius`. Nesse caso, pode tentar dessa forma:

```
.table {
   border-radius: 5px !important
}
```

<kbd>[**!important - Maujor**](http://www.maujor.com/blog/2006/08/18/declaracao-com-important/)</kbd>

Comment: já tentei usando o !important e não foi

Comment: editei o tópico do jeito que está agora e continua sem funcionar, testei também colocando direto o CSS na table{} e não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi exatamente o que você quer. Seria isso?

HTML

```
<table class="borda-na-tabela">
<tr>
<th>ASDFASDF</th>
<th>ASDFASDFASDFA</th>
<th>ASDFASDF</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ASDFASDF</td>
<td>654</td>
<td>R$ 00,00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SDFASDF</td>
<td>45</td>
<td>R$ 00,00</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.borda-na-tabela {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

table td {
    color: #aaa;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table th{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b78k3h7s/2/)

Comment: sua resposta não é a mesma do @helder?

Comment: @AndreyHartung Agora que notei que é praticamente igual. Mas a questão é que pare o que você pediu, da forma que pediu, isso é o que atende. A diferença vendo em execução, é que o meu código gera uma tabela conforme a div do seu exemplo.

Comment: o complicado é que eu já deixei assim e ainda não aparecem as bordas x.x

Comment: @AndreyHartung Você tem sua aplicação rodando em algum link?

Comment: infelizmente não e ainda não posso colocar no ar :/ vou editar aqui como está agora

Comment: editei o tópico do jeito que está agora e continua sem funcionar, testei também colocando direto o CSS na table{} e não funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Você tem que definir a propriedade **overflow** para o valor **hidden**.

Ex.:

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```